# preg_match with international characters and accents

Tags: php, preg-match, non-ascii-characters

I would like to validate a string with a pattern that can only contain letters (including letters with accents). Here is the code I use and it always returns "nok".
I don't know what I am doing wrong, can you help? thanks

```
$string = 'é';

if(preg_match('/^[\p{L}]+$/i', $string)){

    echo 'ok';

} else{

    echo 'nok';
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add the UTF-8 [modifier flag](http://php.net/manual/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (**u**) to your expression:

```
/^\p{L}+$/ui
```

There is also no need to wrap `\p{L}` inside of a character class.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy, trying to get an expression like `/état(.*)/i` trying to match "États-unis" and "états-unis"...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps anybody that will check this question / thread later. The code below allows only letters, accents and spaces. No symbols or punctuation like .,?/>[-< etc.

```
<?php
$string = 'États unis and états unis';

if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z \p{L}]+$/ui', $string)){

echo 'ok';

} else{

echo 'nok';
}

?>
```

If you want to add numbers too, just add 0-9 immediately after Z like this a-zA-Z0-9

Then if you are applying this to form validation and you are scared a client/user might just hit spacebar and submit, just use:

```
if (trim($_POST['forminput']) == "") {... some error message ...}
```

to reject the submission.

Comment: FYI: `[a-zA-Z]` is already included in `\p{L}` and the `/i` flag is useless here. And the question is about letters only, no spaces, punctuations, digits ...