# match special character using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

if i use this it woks just fine:

```
$string = 'prueba Numero de Documento: 0206728108 Gracias';

preg_match('#Numero de Documento: (\w+)#', $string, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

OUTPUTS: **0206728108**

and this does not work:

```
$string = 'prueba Número de Documento: 0206728108 Gracias';

preg_match('#Número de Documento: (\w+)#', $string, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

EMPTY OUTPUT

Comment: not for me...can you please explain why when i use this it works:

`$string = mb_convert_encoding(html_entity_decode($string), "UTF-8","ISO-8859-1");`

Comment: Maybe because in var/string you got (probably value from form?) you have something like this: $string = 'prueba NÃºmero de Documento: 0206728108 Gracias';, and in php code: preg_match('#Número de Documento: (\w+)#', $string, $match)?http://writecodeonline.com/php/ test code online, and check how spec. chars are converted...

Comment: I don't think that `html_entity_decode` would matter there. See if adding the `u` switch helps. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649019/preg-match-with-international-characters-and-accents

Answer (score 0):

Use the `u` modifier for unicode:

```
preg_match('#Número de Documento: (\w+)#u', $string, $match);
//                              here ___^
```